# How to retain popup while doing an action with a button inside it in Asp.Net MVC so that the action result will be displayed in the pop up only?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 application.

In my page I have an **ADD** button which will pop up a window (jquery dialog) and render the ADD view inside that. If the user **clicks the Add button it will update the DB** and redirect to the grid page. But if there are any validation errors (including the server side validations), it returns the same view with the model having errors. But it is closing the popup and showing in a standalone page.

My requirement is to **show the validation errors against the controls by retaining the popup**.

Can anyone please help on this ?

Comment: I don't have the code with me now. But what I am doing is...
Open a jquery dialog...
Inside this load the Add Get action.  So the ADD view will be rendered in the popup.
Then in the Add post action redirect to the List action (grid) if successful or return to the same view with the model which will have the errors...

Comment: No one can help fix your code if you don't show it!

Comment: Yea...  I can understand... But I am out of office and I don't have the code with me now. 

But if anybody can share the idea on how to implement the above scenario, that would help me in trying some sample...

Comment: You can use Ajax -to prevent page reload-, or add cookie on pop-up open, and on page load check if that cookie exist, open pop-up.